# Can't test whether key exists in associative zsh array

Tags: zsh

This is my script (zsh 5.8):

```
# Consider parameter expansion of an unset variable to be an error
set -u  

# Define and populate associative array
typeset -A arr 
arr=(x xxx y yyy)

echo $arr[x] # Outputs xxx

# Test whether key x is present
((${arr[(Ie)x]})) && echo true
```

The last line gives me the error *zsh: x: parameter not set*, and from this message I conclude that zsh treats the `x` not literally, but as a variable which zsh wants to expand. Why do I have a variable expansion here, and how can I write test (without violating `set -u`) for checking that the key *x* is present in the array?

I know that I can of course write an explicit loop over the keys (i.e. `for k in ${(k)arr}`, but I suspect that there must be an easier way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the key `x` is present in `arr`, `${arr[(Ie)x]}` expands to the list of keys that match `x`, which is just `x`. This results in the arithmetic expression `x`, which evaluates to the numerical value of `x`. But `x` is unset, hence the error that you see.

Generally, [be careful with associative arrays in arithmetic expressions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/627474/how-to-use-associative-arrays-safely-inside-arithmetic-expressions).

`[[ $arr[(Ie)x] ]]` would work for a non-empty key. Alternatively, `((${+arr[x]}))` is more common, but I don't see any advantage to it: it also doesn't work with empty keys. I think that the `$+` approach works for arbitrary keys if you use an intermediate variable:

```
key=x # or '' or ']' …
(($+arr[$key]))
```

Answer (score 2):

With associative arrays in Zsh, you can test whether the key exists with `[[ -v dict[key] ]]`. You can read about the conditional flags like `-v` [here](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html#Conditional-Expressions).

Remember, when using `-v`, don't prefix your dict variable with a `$`. You are checking the named variable exists, not the value it may contain.

Here's a simple example:

```zsh
$ # declare an associative array
$ typeset -A fruits=(banana yellow strawberry red blueberry blue)
$ # print out all the keys with (k) and values with (v)
$ echo ${(k)fruits}
banana strawberry blueberry
```

Now, let's show how `-v` works:

```zsh
if ! [[ -v fruits[apple] ]]; then
  echo "no apples here"
fi

if [[ -v fruits[banana] ]]; then
  echo "monkey business"
fi

for k in ${(k)fruits} orange pineapple; do
  [[ -v fruits[$k] ]] && echo "$k exists" || echo "$k missing"
done
```

This will output:

```
no apples here
monkey business
banana exists
strawberry exists
blueberry exists
orange missing
pineapple missing
```